# Using Callable In ROOM

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-room, callable

I am building TODO app with room database and MVVM.

So since I can't use ROOM in main thread,I searched for solutions and came across "Callable" which is just what I need!

Since I have more than 5 functions that make database calls, I wonder **how I can use the same Callable code instead of writing it 5 times in different functions.**

**This is how I currently doing it:**

```
public List<Task> getAllUnCompletedTasksAsList() {

    Callable<List<Task>> callable = new Callable<List<Task>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Task> call() throws Exception {
            return appDataBase.taskDao().getAllUnCompletedTasksAsList();
        }
    };

    Future<List<Task>> future = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(callable);

    try {
        return future.get();
    } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public List<Task> getCompletedTasksAsList() {

    Callable<List<Task>> callable = new Callable<List<Task>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Task> call() throws Exception {
            return appDataBase.taskDao().getCompletedTasksAsList();
        }
    };

    Future<List<Task>> future = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(callable);

    try {
        return future.get();
    } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public List<Task> getWeeklyTasksAsList() {

    Callable<List<Task>> callable = new Callable<List<Task>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Task> call() throws Exception {
            return appDataBase.taskDao().getWeeklyTasksAsList();
        }
    };

    Future<List<Task>> future = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(callable);

    try {
        return future.get();
    } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

I would love to hear your suggestions,Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating an anonymous inner class. Do it once outside the methods and use the field instance of your `Callable`.

```
private Callable<List<Task>> callable = new Callable<List<Task>>() {
    @Override
    public List<Task> call() throws Exception {
        return appDataBase.taskDao().getAllUnCompletedTasksAsList();
    }
};
```

And (for example)

```
public List<Task> getAllUnCompletedTasksAsList() {
    /*
    Callable<List<Task>> callable = new Callable<List<Task>>() {
        @Override
        public List<Task> call() throws Exception {
            return appDataBase.taskDao().getAllUnCompletedTasksAsList();
        }
    };
    */
    Future<List<Task>> future = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(this.callable);

    try {
        return future.get();
    } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Elliott but it's the same, I still have to write more callables, just outside the functions with different appDataBase calls